# Swing classes are extremely slow displaying RTL text

Tags: java, swing, java-11, java-12

I am confronted with this centuries old issue in Swing and RTL languages. Whenever it comes to show Hebrew text in Swing components of any kind, the application just melts the CPU by font metrics calculations. I see the issue mentioned a [decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333577/string-width-via-fontmetrics-calculation-is-very-slow-if-there-are-arabic-or-per), then it popped up in [Oracle](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8195089) and recently in [Open JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8195089) bug repositories. People are even trying to [hack the JRE](https://hackernoon.com/the-curious-case-of-hebrew-rendering-in-java-swing-2c656537c98b) by replacing the implementations with instrumentation tools.

This is an extremely old issue and it's unbelievable that it manifests itself in Java 8,9,10,11 and 12. Actually starting from Java 9 and up the usage of HTML with RTL in Swing components brings its rendering to a screeching halt making the entire app useless.

If anybody knows how to deal with this, please do share.

Comment: I take the fact that this bug is out there for so long, and that you already found multiple links to defects and such things as: probably there is nothing you can do about it. I also find it very unlikely that you will learn anything here that you didn't find on any of the resources you already collected. From that point of view I consider your question extremely interesting, but too broad for this community.

Comment: Broad in what way? It's razor focused - the existing swing applications in JRE 9+ using HTML in their components to render RTL languages will killl your app. Broadly speaking :)

Comment: I think I explained why I dont see much chances for your question. If my assignment is correct or not, well, lets count the votes tomorrow morning.